# Unable to receive updated value from sharedPreference in Android Service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

Iam stuck with this problem for more than 4 hours, iam unable to pass an updated value from a sharedPrefernce in Service class.

```
public class Background extends Service {
.....
.....
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
....
....
private void callService() {
    String prefCount=getSharedData("list_update_count");
    myb = new myBroad();
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    myb.SetAlarm(context,prefCount);
}
....
....
public class myListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
    {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE)
        {
            String phoneNumber =   incomingNumber;
            callService();
        }
    }  

}
```

My BroadcastReceiver ------------------------------------------

```
    public class myBroad extends BroadcastReceiver{
    .....
    .....
    .....
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ....
    .....
    }
    public void SetAlarm(Context context,String prefCount){
        //here the prefCount is not receiving the updated value!!
    buildToast(prefCount,context);
    }
.....
}
```

When i launch the application after a force stop, The updated value from the sharedPreference is obtained correctly.
Thanks ...

Comment: put your logcat message here

Comment: I cant see anything in the logcat o/p .im not familiar with logcat maybe because of that¡

Comment: paste your log cat here it will be more important to solve error

Comment: @RahulMandaliya, I solved the issue by changing the sharedPref to SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);.Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: good, if you have any problem then first express brief, paste your logic and then logcat error list, so other can understand exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try this?

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Sorry, Global is my own class that contains constants used on my projects, replace Global.PREFERENCES to your own SharedPreferences name.

Comment: Can you please elobrate ? about Global.PREFERENCES ,please . .

Comment: Saved my day.. Thanks @user3381480

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is deprecated. Please update your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", 0);
     String prefCount = pref.getString("list_update_count", 0)
```

or in case you are using default sharedPreferences

```
 SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
 String prefCount = pref.getString("list_update_count", 0);
```